Stringers to deck attachment
I'm uncertain about the end joist & backboard connection to the stringers. I've had some mixed feedback on other websites. In hindsight I could have made the stairs flush with the deck so that all of the stringers are sitting against the end joist, which would have provided for stronger support. However, many stairs are made in this manner and, in fact, they are aesthetically more pleasing as well, at least to me.
Is the connection to the stringers adequate, and if not, how can I provide that connection so that it is, without a doubt, adequate. Or, perhaps, I should just add two posts at the top of the stairs as seen in the model image? Any other feedback would be appreciated.
A few FYIs

I plan on adding mid-span stair posts with a beam
I will add joist tape
I will extend the concrete landing a bit more so that the stringers are fully sitting on a surface.





IDK if it's right, but I'd put some "cross joists" across the bottom of the joists, butted up against that plate the stringers are butted up against.
